# Postgres relationship statement

Tags: postgresql, relations

Lets say I have the table parents. A parent has many kids and a kid has many toys What would be the best way to do a SELECT statement for the parent and grab all of kids associated with that parent and all the toys associated the that kid?

Comment: My answer was upvoted yesterday - so I put all of the data and SQL into  a fiddle - might be of interest to you - though at 5yrs and 4 days, maybe not? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start to answer this question, I created 4 tables (see the end of the post for sample data - or better still, see the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=e1945e9329ddf1c8409f450329e5313f)):

```
CREATE TABLE parent (parent_id INTEGER, parent_name VARCHAR(20));
CREATE TABLE child (child_id INTEGER, parent_id INTEGER, child_name VARCHAR(20));
CREATE TABLE toy (toy_id INTEGER, toy_name VARCHAR(40));
CREATE TABLE child_toy (child_id INTEGER, toy_id INTEGER);
```

This last table is a "joining table" which maintains an m-n connection between two others (in this case, child and toy). There are many childen and many toys and children can have more than one toy.

I leave it as an exercise to put in the necessary `FOREIGN KEY` constraints. You can also use Oracle `SEQUENCE`s rather than explicitly inputting ids.

Now, this query will produce all toys for all children for all parents.

```
SELECT 
  p.parent_name, 
  c.child_name,
  t.toy_name
FROM parent p
  INNER JOIN child c
  ON p.parent_id = c.parent_id
  INNER JOIN child_toy ct 
  ON c.child_id = ct.child_id
  INNER JOIN toy t
  ON ct.toy_id = t.toy_id;
```

Result:

```
parent_name;child_name;toy_name
Fred;Jimmy;Barbie
Fred;Jimmy;Monopoly
..
<lines deleted>
..
Joe;Helen;Soccer ball
Joe;Helen;Rugby ball
```

You can play around with the fiddle ([here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=e1945e9329ddf1c8409f450329e5313f)) and experiment with it to develop your SQL skills.

- Find all children who don't have a toy.
- Find all parents none of whose children has a toy.
- Find the child who has the most toys.
- Find the parent whose children have the most toys.
- Find all children who only have 1 toy (more than 1, less than 3... &c.).

You may need to input further sample data for this.

Here's a small hint:

```
SELECT 
  p.parent_name, 
  c.child_name,
  COUNT(t.toy_id)
FROM parent p
  INNER JOIN child c
  ON p.parent_id = c.parent_id
  INNER JOIN child_toy ct 
  ON c.child_id = ct.child_id
  INNER JOIN toy t
  ON ct.toy_id = t.toy_id
GROUP BY p.parent_name, c.child_name
HAVING (COUNT(t.toy_id) > 3);

parent_name;child_name;count
Fred;Jimmy;4
```

So, child Jimmy with parent Fred has more than 3 toys. There endless combinations which you can try out! Enjoy!

**============== Sample Data =============**

### parent:

```
INSERT INTO parent VALUES (1, 'Fred');
INSERT INTO parent VALUES (2, 'Mary');
INSERT INTO parent VALUES (3, 'Joe');
```

### child:

```
INSERT INTO child VALUES (1, 1, 'Jimmy');
INSERT INTO child VALUES (2, 1, 'Gerry');
INSERT INTO child VALUES (3, 1, 'Billy');
INSERT INTO child VALUES (4, 2, 'Mick');
INSERT INTO child VALUES (5, 2, 'James');
INSERT INTO child VALUES (6, 2, 'Larry');
INSERT INTO child VALUES (7, 3, 'Jim');
INSERT INTO child VALUES (8, 3, 'Jack');
INSERT INTO child VALUES (9, 3, 'Helen');
```

### toy:

```
INSERT INTO toy VALUES (1, 'Action Man');
INSERT INTO toy VALUES (2, 'Barbie');
INSERT INTO toy VALUES (3, 'Monopoly');
INSERT INTO toy VALUES (4, 'Cluedo');
INSERT INTO toy VALUES (5, 'Hurley');
INSERT INTO toy VALUES (6, 'Soccer ball');
INSERT INTO toy VALUES (7, 'Rugby ball');
INSERT INTO toy VALUES (8, 'Tennis ball');
INSERT INTO toy VALUES (9, 'Tennis raquet');
INSERT INTO toy VALUES (10, 'Tricycle');
```

### child_toy:

```
INSERT INTO child_toy VALUES(1, 2);
INSERT INTO child_toy VALUES(1, 3);
INSERT INTO child_toy VALUES(1, 4);
INSERT INTO child_toy VALUES(1, 5);
INSERT INTO child_toy VALUES(2, 3);
INSERT INTO child_toy VALUES(2, 9);
INSERT INTO child_toy VALUES(3, 1);
INSERT INTO child_toy VALUES(3, 2);
INSERT INTO child_toy VALUES(4, 6);
INSERT INTO child_toy VALUES(5, 7);
INSERT INTO child_toy VALUES(6, 9);
INSERT INTO child_toy VALUES(7, 3);
INSERT INTO child_toy VALUES(8, 4);
INSERT INTO child_toy VALUES(9, 5);
INSERT INTO child_toy VALUES(9, 6);
INSERT INTO child_toy VALUES(9, 7);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a lot more detail to your question; but in general it's simply a matter of using a `JOIN` statement to join two tables on a common key column:

```
SELECT *
FROM Parents p
    INNER JOIN Children c ON p.ParentID = c.ParentID
    INNER JOIN Toys t ON c.ChildID = t.ChildID
WHERE p.ParentID = 1;
```